# automake failing, says it requires Makefile.in

Tags: makefile, automake

I am attempting to set up a GNU autotools project. My file structure currently looks like this:

```
myproject
  |- configure.ac
  |- Makefile.am {SUBDIRS = doc src}
  |- doc
  |    |- Makefile.am
  |- src
  |    |- Makefile.am
  |    |- {source files}
```

The AC_CONFIG_FILES macro reads

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile
                 doc/Makefile
                 src/Makefile])
```

The problem is that, when I run `automake` from the `myproject` directory, I get the following error:

```
configure.ac:28: error: required file 'doc/Makefile.in' not found
```

where line 28 is where the `AC_CONFIG_FILES` macro begins. I thought `automake` was supposed to *produce* `Makefile.in`, so why is it complaining that it's a required file?

Comment: How do you run automake?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer I just call ``automake`` with no arguments

Comment: Did you invoke `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` in your `configure.ac`?

Comment: @MadScientist Yup, right after ``AC_INIT``

Comment: could you post a minimal example project that exhibits the problem?

Comment: You should also probably try using `autoreconf -fis` instead of `automake`.